# Find the extremals $y(x)$ and $ z(x) $ for the functional

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the extremals $y(x)$ and $z(x)$ for the functional $$J(y,z)=\int_{0}^{1} (z^2-2y^2) dx$$ subject to the 
boundary conditions $ \ \ y(0)=1 \ $ , a natural boundary condition at $ \ x=1 \ $ , and subject to the constraint

$$y'-y-z=0$$

**Answer:**

The given constraint is

$ \ y'-y-z=0 \ $

or $ \ z=y'-y \ $

The functional is

$ J[x,y,y]=\int_{0}^{1} [(y'-y)^2-2y^2]dx $  (Substituting the
value of  $z$)

Then ,

$ F(x,y,y')=y'^2-2yy'+y^2 \ $ .

The  Euler  equation is

$ F_y-(F_y')^{'} \ =0 $ ,  or, $ \ y''+y=0 \ $ ,

or, $ \ y(x)=A \cos x+B \sin x \ $

Using the boundary condition $ y(0)=1 $ , we get

$ A=1 \ $

Thus,

$ y(x)=\cos x+B \sin x \ $ .

Now I have to apply **natural boundary condition at $ x=1 \ $** to get the constant $ B $ .

But I don't know how to apply the **natural boundary condition at $ x=1 \ $** .

**Is there any help ?**

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what a natural boundary condition is? Math terminology varies between different textbooks.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, it might be a zero Neumann boundary condition. Under this interpretation, we would have $B = \tan(1)$.

Comment: yes I got it . Thanks